# Getting the class from index of Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3,4],'Name':['Andi','Boby','Charlie','Daniel'],'Occupation':['x','xxx','xxx','x']})
```

and

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3,4],'Occupation':['x','xxx','xxx','x'],'Class':[1,0,1,0]})
```

Based on the index i want to get the class based on index, so i create another dataframe by merging both of the df1 and df2. I used

```
data1=df1.merge(df2,on='index',how='left')
```

The result is i am having two columns Occupation_x and Occupation_y. How do i merge the dataframe without having those Occupation_x and Occupation_y columns therefore the columns would be index, Name, Occupation, Class

Comment: Drop the Occupation_x column and rename the Occupation_y column to Occupation

Comment: Yes, that would be an easy job, but when the features is more than 10, you will have problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While merging specify `right_on` and `left_on` to avoid Occupation_x and Occupation_y

Comment: thanks, lets say we have more than 10 features, is there any way to avoid making features1_x, features1_y. with right_on or left_on we need to specify all the feaures.

Comment: You can use `suffixes=('_x', '_y')` while merging to set the name of the repeating columns formed as  col1_x col1_y to col and col_any_string and than through regex (_any_string) drop those columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could join using only the index and class in df2

```
data1=df1.join(df2[['Class']])
```

Comment: Thanks, what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Before merging add this line

```
df2.pop('Occupation') # this line needs to be added
data1=df1.merge(df2,on='index', how='left')
```

If you have more than one such columns, try the below method

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2'] # Add required columns of df2 here
data1=df1.merge(df2[cols],on='index', how='left')
```